# How to subtracting two hyperspectral image?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, subtraction, spectral-python

I would like to subtracting two hyperspectral images with different shapes  using numpy and spectral python,

```
var1 = np.subtract(arrWHITEREF, arrImg)
```

but it shows me an error that operation can not be broadcast together because of different shapes

> arrImg shape is (2495, 1312, 784) and arrWHITEREF shape is  (10, 1312,
>   784)

How can I subtracting two hyperspectral images ?

.

Comment: yeah, same shape arrays could only be subtracted or one of the arrays should be broadcastable to the shape of another. For your arrays, last two dimensions work out ok but the axis-0 is the problem

Comment: @kmario23 one idea could be convert the arrays to matrix then subtracting them but I am not sure they I will lose data or not